# Webcam set up small circle tunnel vision type view

Tags: telescope

I've just adapted a webcam for my telescope.

I'm new to astronomy so I'm not sure if the view I get is right.

When I attached the webcam to my [Barlow lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_lens), the view on my laptop becomes a tiny circle of light, like a tunneling effect.

Is this normal? How could I make the view I see on screen lager?

Here is what I'm currently seeing:

[image]

Comment: You may consider to make your question ready.

Comment: The question is fairly clear and should not be closed for "unclear what you are asking". The OP placed a webcam right behind a Barlow lens. This is not the correct configuration, and so an answer would explain how to do this correctly. However, that image looks a bit like Jupiter (or maybe the Moon?) and a star (though it really be just a "blob" and a reflection) so I think it would be great if we knew what the telescope was pointed at. Can you explain where the telescope was pointed? Also, did you modify the webcam by removing the lens? This would be important to know.